# Is a pointer the same as a byte address?

Tags: c++, pointers, byte

Assume I have an array declared like this:

```
int *p = new int[size];
```

And `p` will of course point to the address of the first element. But since a byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory, does `p` actually point to the first *byte* of the first 4 bytes of the first element of the array?

Comment: Some OS/compiler may have decreasing addressed bytes some increasing?. Endianness?

Comment: How would you know the difference?

Comment: To be correct, you haven't "declared an array". You've *declared a pointer", and initialized it to point to the first element of an array. The array itself has no name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address of an `int` is not necessarily exactly the same as the address of the first byte (`char`) in its object representation. This is because some machines have native pointer registers that lack bits, such that `sizeof (char *) != sizeof (int *)` is possible.

Discounting that, though, the `int *` is *convertible* to the pointer to the first byte of the object representation via `static_cast< char * >( p )`. You can pass the resulting pointer to `std::memcpy` to initialize another `int` or any POD class type whose first member is an `int`. ("First byte" therefore is defined as the one with the lowest address.)

For any machine you're likely to encounter in general-purpose computing, `char *` and `int *` are physically the same thing; their differences are just enforced by the compiler for the purpose of code safety. But there do exist exotic architectures where `static_cast` does something meaningful in this situation and something like `reinterpret_cast` would entirely fail perform the correct conversion.

Comment: For more of a lesson, the poster should execute `cout << p << " " << p + 1 << endl;`.  Then,  he should write `char *pc = static_cast< char * >( p )` and then `cout << pc << " " << pc + 1 << endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it indeed points to the first of the four bytes.  In the case of big Endian, the four bytes will look like 0 0 0 1.  In the case of little Endian, the bytes will look like 1 0 0 0.  So, just to be sure, in the case of big Endian, the first byte will contain a 0 while in the case of little Endian, the first byte will contain a 1.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to says the lowest address of the four bytes, because "first" leaves room for questions of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Because p is initialized as an int*, each element of p will take the number of bytes that an int does. To clarify:

```
int* p = new int[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    p[i] = i;
cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << " " << p[3];
```

This would output "0 1 2 3." You do not have to worry about individual bytes. In general, this is also true:

```
*p = p[0];
```